# unlink() doesn't work with absolute path

Tags: php, unlink

I'm working on a method which delete pictures using `unlink()`. However I can't find a way to make it work using absolute path.

Here is my code :

```
$img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/i/koala.png';
unlink($img);
```

Error :

```
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/i/koala.png): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/king/test.php on line 15
```

Any help?

Comment: Verify the path, it‘s probably wrong

Comment: What happens when you log into the terminal and type: `ls /var/www/html/i/koala.png` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cobble together various strings to make a path, you should use `realpath` to verify it and convert any relative fragments like `/../`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/i/koala.png';
$img = realpath($path);
```

$img will either be false, or a string of a valid path!

Comment: my $img variable becomes NULL using realpath()

Comment: I split that line in 2. `die($path);` and whatever comes out, go to the terminal and type `ls /the/path/it/gave/you.php`

Comment: ls: cannot access '/var/www/html/..': No such file or directory

Comment: however I can access this exact same path with my FTP

Comment: FTP? That'll be a completely different folder surely?

Comment: ohh wait, it worked. I was still seeing the image because it was cached. thanks

Comment: glad i could help! have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

check it now

```
$filename = '/var/www/html/i/koala.png';

if(file_exists($filename))
{
  chmod($filename, 777);
  unlink($filename);
  echo "file has deleted";
}
else
{
 echo "file not exists";
}
```

Comment: it returns "file not exists" however the absolute path is working